# Will using Winemaker's Acid Blend to adjust mash pH have a flavor impact on beer?

Tags: beer, mash-ph

I got a pH meter for Christmas and today was my first chance to try it out.  Unfortunately, I didn't think to get any lactic acid.

I found that my mash pH was at about 5.8 at 148F, so I put a little bit of "Winemaker's acid blend" into the mash, which brought the pH down to 5.3 at the same temperature, which seems to be right in the middle of the "ideal" pH range.

The blend is a mixture of Citric, Malic, and Tartaric acids, and I'm wondering if using that will have any significant flavor impact on my beer.    I see in "How To Brew" that Phosphoric Acid reacts with the Calcium and changes various things about the mash chemistry, but I don't see anything on any of the acids in the blend.

I suppose I could break out my wife's old chemistry text book and try to relearn how to do the reaction formulas, but I'm hoping someone here might have an idea.

Answer (score 1):

pH should be measured and reported at room temp, about 70F.  The idea that pHosphoric acid will negatively affect Ca is pretty much outdated and disproven.  I doubt that your acid blend will have any negative affects, but it really depends on how much you used.  For more info about water, pH, and how to adjust it, see https://sites.google.com/site/brunwater/ .

Comment: I used less than 1/4 teaspoon of it, with 8 gallons of water and 17lbs of malt.

Comment: In that case, I can't imagine it will have a flavor impact.

Comment: Me either, really, but I figured I would ask.   The bit about phosphoric changing the chemistry around had me a little concerned about using those.